# Couldn't install git-flow on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, git-flow

I am trying to install `git-flow` on Ubuntu 10.04 but I am getting the following error:

```
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package git-flow
```

I have exected these instructions

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-flow
```

But didn't work. I got the above error. I am able to install using the following commands

```
wget -P ~/Downloads http://launchpadlibrarian.net/84618376/git-flow_0.4.1-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/git-flow_0.4.1-2_all.deb
```

But I don't understand why the first set of commands doesn't work. What could be the possible issue.

Comment: Try asking this over on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), the StackExchange network for Server Systems.

Comment: Probaly `git-flow` is not avaible for `Ubuntu 10.4`, before trying to install it check if the package is avabile with `apt-cache search git-flow`

Answer (score 2):

`git-flow` is available for [12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=git-flow), [13.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&searchon=names&keywords=git-flow), [13.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&searchon=names&keywords=git-flow) and [14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git-flow&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all). Unfortunately it has not been added to the [10.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&searchon=names&keywords=git-flow) repository. Sad panda.

Answer (score -1):

In the default repositories of Ubuntu there is no git-flow package.

I'm currently not aware of any 3rd parties repositories from which you can install git-flow.